# Proof that any fractional number squared is also fractional?

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing

Let **a** belong to the set of (Rationals - Integers)

How would you prove the following:

> **a** squared belongs to the set of (Rationals - Integers)

Comment: The body of the question doesn't match the title. Which one are you asking? In case it matters, remember that $\,i^2=-1\,$, and $\big(\sqrt{2}\big)^2=2$.

Comment: Sorry I meant set of Complex minus set of Integers

Comment: $i^2=-1$ your statement is false.

Comment: Ah yes of course. I'm going to update the question to be irrational set minus integer.

Comment: If the dupes don't answer your question then please clarify why and we can reopen the question.